# In an React/Redux app, is it possible somehow to let the user decide the text design?

Tags: forms, reactjs, text, redux, styling

In my blogproject ive been using forms to collect the heading, text and img from users, but now ive realized this gives the user little control over the presentation of the text since they cant control the headings, fonts, links etc. As i am posting this question i see that this form would be awesome to use, meaning stackoverflows question[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQZCz.png)form. Anyone has any pointers? any modules or libraries i can use?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) a lot lately.  One of its central purposes (and one of the reasons why it was built in the first place) is to allow for simple theming.

Maybe you could integrate its [theming capabilities](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) with a select system for font and padding, colors, etc.?